# Hyperledger BESU nodes keep restarting after some days

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-besu

I have a question about production hyperledger BESU.
I have deployed a private hyperledger BESU via the dev-quickstart. I figured out that  after 10 days, some docker container start restarting and I am not able to connect to hyperledger, even if I restart the network. After remove and run again, it operates as expected.

So I guess it has to do with the memory of the docker containers, since the size of the container is growing after storing data etc.

So I have 2 questions

- Is there any best practice in order not to have that kind of problems in the future ? (like saving the data and logs outside the docker etc)
- Except the state data and the transaction's data, what other data a peer saves during the transactions?

Thank you in advance